# Viewport changing in libgdx viewport

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have 2 screens: a level select screen which uses a FitViewport with a resolution of 720 x 405 and then a game screen which uses a FillViewport with a resolution of 480 x 270 scaled by the amount of pixels per meter (/100).

After completing a certain level I want to return to the level select screen. However, upon return it seems to be fully zoomed in.

[Here is how it should look, and how it looks when first launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9iyh.png)

[Here is how it looks after coming out of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKaYW.png)

Here is the level screen code:

```
public LevelScreen(CrossplatformApp game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    this.levelstage = new Stage(new FitViewport(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, camera));
    this.background = new Texture("Screens/LevelScreen/LevelSelection.png");
    this.backbutton = new Texture("Screens/BackButton.png");
    this.level1texture = new Texture("Screens/LevelScreen/Button1.png");
    this.level2texture = new Texture("Screens/LevelScreen/Button2.png");
    this.level3texture = new Texture("Screens/LevelScreen/Button3.png");
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    levelstage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```

And the game screen:

```
this.game = gameFile;
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    this.viewport = new FillViewport(Constants.V_WIDTH / Constants.PPM, Constants.V_HEIGHT / Constants.PPM, camera);
    this.levelHUD = new HUD(gameFile.batch, WorldPicker.getWorldName(playerMemory.player.worldAndLevelData.getCurrentWorld(), playerMemory.player.worldAndLevelData.getCurrentLevel()));
```

Comment: what is common between those two screens ?

Comment: what do you mean with common?

Comment: Do you sharing something like stage, camera, viewport  or anything else ?

Comment: Apart from the main file (crossplatformapplication, which holds the batch) which is shared among all screens e.g. this.game = gameFile and this.game = game, nothing

Comment: Are you using `gameFile.batch` on `LevelScreen`, if yes set projection matrix of batch with combined matrix of camera

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, adding `game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(levelstage.getCamera().combined);` inside the render method of level screen fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When changing viewports you need to apply the viewport before drawing with:

```
this.viewport.apply();
```

Comment: I have tried this. It does not change anything. The viewport.getWidth and getHeight are correct and the type also is correct.